# Using variable in Stored Procedure in ROWS BETWEEN clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables, procedure

What am trying to achieve is:

Get an input value in a variable e.g. `@vNoOfRows = 5` and use the variable in getting `AVG(marks_total)` as below:

```
select avg(marks_total) over (partition by CourseName order by BatchID rows between @vNoOfRows preceding and current row)
```

The stored-procedure works fine if I replace `@vNoOfRows` to be any number e.g. 5 but gives me following compilation error when trying to get the variable working:

> Incorrect syntax near '@vNoOfRows'

Question: What am I missing - and how do I get it working with variables?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add the syntax you are using of declaring `@vNoOfRows` and calling the store procedure?

Comment: You can't use a variable here (without making the whole query dynamic). Check out the [Syntax for OVER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#syntax). **all** that you're allowed for specifying a number is an *unsigned integer literal*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you could achieve this using Dynamic SQL:

```
declare @vNoOfRows int = 5
declare @sql varchar(4000)

set @sql = 'select avg(marks_total) over(partition by CourseName order by BatchID rows between ' + convert(varchar,@vNoOfRows) + ' preceding and current row) from someTable'
exec @sql
```

In response to your comment, if you want to push the result of the query into a variable, you could do this:

```
declare @vNoOfRows int = 5
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
declare @output int

set @sql = 'select @output = avg(marks_total) over(partition by CourseName order by BatchID rows between ' + convert(nvarchar(11), @vNoOfRows) + ' preceding and current row) from someTable'
exec sp_executesql @sql,
    N'@output int OUTPUT',
    @output = @output OUTPUT;
```

Comment: Couple questions on above: Is there a way to get value of exec @sql into a variable? And from a performance perspective, will dynamic sql be slower?

Comment: Glad your problem has been solved. If the answer was helpful, please accept and upvote it. Thanks.

Comment: I've also updated the answer to respond to your question about storing the result of the query in a variable.

Comment: With regards to performance, dynamic SQL may be slower as EXEC by default doesn't cache query plans. SP_EXECUTESQL allows caching.